# LinkButton as a Default Button

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm using linkbuttons in my web applications, my 'composite controls' aren't using ASP Panels (therefore no 'DefaultButton' property, not that it would work). My link buttons currently have the href set as 'javascript:_doPostBack..' (asp default), but to enable my custom client side validation script, I ALSO have code in an 'onclick' attribute.

Typical Button :

```
<div class="button orange o_lime right Normal">
    <a onclick="if (!validateFormmainContent_Login()) return false;" 
        id="mainContent_Login_ctl09_mainContent_Login_btnSubmit" defaultB="loginForm" 
        href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$mainContent$Login$ctl09$mainContent_Login_btnSubmit&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">
        Submit
    </a>
</div>
```

Typical Form row requiring 'default button' action

```
<div class='row' ID='mainContent_Login_ctl03'>
    <label ID='mainContent_Login_ctl04'>Email/Username</label>
    <input name="ctl00$mainContent$Login$txtAccount" type="text" id="mainContent_Login_txtAccount" class="lime validate[required]" defaultB="loginForm" />
</div>
```

My current attempt at code to make this work :

```
<script type="javascript">  
$('input[defaultB]').keypress(function (e) {
    if ((e.which && e.which == 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13)) {     
        $('a[defaultB=' + $(e.srcElement).attr('defaultB') + ']').click();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

My current attempted solution assigns a value to 'defaultB' with something that matches the  'defaultB' value defined in a corresponding button, such that key press '13' (enter) should initiate the 'click' event. but nothing is happening :(

I've created a jsfiddle to help, but it isn't working with stupid 'cant find function' exception. :(

http://jsfiddle.net/Ninjanoel/yQvKC/

I'd really like to get this working without having to rework all my controls! Can anyone help?

Comment: Thank for the two answers thus far, just to say I have embedded some 'alerts' in the different stages in the fiddle, I basically need it to hit all the alerts before I'm happy it works properly. If the message in '__doPostBack' will always be inaccessible, I'd like a good reason why. Thanks everyone.

Comment: I'm basically trying to design a solution where I can add an attribute ('defaultB' in this case) to both the text field and the 'a' tag acting as a button, and have it automatically act as if the ASP linkbutton has been clicked by the mouse (kicking off the href javascript and the onclick event code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('input[defaultB]').keypress(function (e) {
    if ((e.which && e.which == 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13)) {  
         alert('enter pressed');    
        var _el = $('a[defaultB='+ $(e.srcElement).attr('defaultB') + ']');
        eval(_el.attr('onclick'));
        eval(_el.attr('href'));
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ninjanoel/5WDKT/1/

Is my use of 'eval' in this instance dangerous? The use of 'eval' on the attributes seems to do the trick for me, but I wonder if it's too much of a security risk to do it this way?

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the code see:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/yQvKC/5/
```

What i belive you are missing is: **$(this)**

I use

```
  $('a[defaultB=' + $(this).attr('defaultB') + ']').click();
```

then
     $('a[defaultB=' + $(e.srcElement).attr('defaultB') + ']').click();

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this is still not doing the 'button click' properly, and your changes dont make sense, and your fiddle doesn't demonstrate it working properly, I want the alert message in several places to all fire

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you bind the keypress event to the input button. So if the user presses the button and then presses enter, the event will be triggered. You should bind it to the form!

I've updated the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/YN56H/2/

You may have to work on the selection of the default button (according to the ugly generated html from asp.net), but I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this is still not doing the 'button click' properly. As this is ASP, I need the message 'doing postbacl' (typo in code) to appear, it is not, therefore it's still not working. And, doing it on the form is not appropriate because I need the value in 'defaultB' on the text box being editted so I can then use that 'defaultB' value to find the appropriate button to click.

Comment: Also, moving the code out of the 'onclick' into a $(id).click() is not ideal for my situation.